# Is there exist a group homomorphism from the symmetric group $S_n$ to $S_{n-1}$ for $n \ge 5?$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism

Does there  exist  a group homomorphism from  the  symmetric group $S_n$  to  $S_{n-1}$ for  $n \ge 5?$

My attempt: I think not,  because  for  $n \ge 5$ , $A_n$ is  the  only  normal  subgroup of $S_n$.

Is it true?

Comment: The trivial homomorphism?

Answer (score 4):

As you are aware that $A_n$ is a normal subgroup how about trying for a homomorphism that will have $A_n$ as its kernel.

Take any permutation $\tau\in S_{n-1}$ of order 2. For example $\tau =(17)(38)(26)\in S_8$. (cycle notation).

Define for $\sigma\in A_n$, $\phi(\sigma) =id$, and $\phi(\sigma)=\tau$ for $\sigma\in S_n-A_n$. This is a nontrivial homomorphism with image a subgroup of order $2$. This shows that in fact there are as many homomorphims as there are elemnts of order 2 in $S_{n-1}$. The same argument works by replacing the codomain $S_{n-1}$ by any group of even order (they always have elements of order 2).

Comment: Good approach.  The way the question is phrased with the restriction on $n$ makes me think something is missing.